# Do bipartite unitary operators always have a "non-entangling" basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Let's say I have a unitary operator $U: A \otimes B \to A \otimes B$. Will there exist a basis for $A \otimes B$ consisting of non-entangled vectors which do not become entangled under $U$? If not, what are the counter-examples. If so, why?

edit: slightly clarified the wording in the title.

Comment: Orthonormal basis, or any basis?  (And is there a motivation behind the question?) -- BTW, I does not even seem obvious whether there is even a single state of that form.

Comment: Orthonormal ideally, but any basis would do (but I get the feeling that you could use such a basis to construct an orthonormal basis).

Comment: I guess that for qubits, one can brute-force it, using that up to local unitaries, any two qubit gate is of the form $\exp(i(a\,XX + b\, YY+c\, ZZ))$.