Time evolution keeps a certain product state always a product state. Is there a time-independent factorizable evolution for this state?
I am typically thinking of quantum spin chains in the following of some length $L$. I am OK without any locality in the assumptions on $H$.
I have a product state $|\psi\rangle$ and a potentially very complicated time-independent Hamiltonian $H$ with many interactions. The only restriction on $H$ is that $e^{-i H t} |\psi\rangle$ is always a product state for all times $t$.
Can I find a completely factorizable time evolution generated by a different (and now field-like) Hamiltonian $\tilde{H} = \sum_i \tilde{h}_i$ ($\tilde{h}_i$ only has support on site $i$) that mimics the time evolution of the complicated $H$ on this state?
That is, can I always find time-independent $\tilde{h}_i$ such that $$e^{-i H t} |\psi\rangle = \otimes_i e^{-i \tilde{h}_i t} |\psi \rangle$$ for all times $t$? In particular, I require that $\tilde{h}_i$ does not change in time.

This question is a simplification of a couple related questions that I've asked. The main difference between those questions and the current one is a simplification to the time evolution of just a single state rather than considering a larger subspace of the Hilbert space and the strong simplification to just consider product states rather than generic entangled states whose entanglement doesn't change.

As pointed out by Norbert Schuch in the comments, a similar result bipartite case would imply this. In particular, suppose that we knew that if conditions $1$ and $2$ held, then result $3$ follows:
If

$|\psi\rangle$ were factorizable across a bipartition into $A$ and $B$, and
time evolution of $|\psi\rangle$ under $H$ preserved factorizability across $A$ and $B$,

then

$e^{-iHt}|\psi\rangle = e^{-iH_A t} \otimes e^{-iH_B t} |\psi\rangle$ holds for time-independent $H_A$ and $H_B$ with support on $A$ and $B$.

Then under the stronger assumption that $|\psi\rangle$ is a product state and remains a product state under time evolution by $H$, we would get $e^{-iHt}|\psi\rangle = e^{-iH_A t} \otimes e^{-iH_B t} |\psi\rangle$ for any bipartition into $A$ and $B$. But then from the assumption on $|\psi\rangle$, the state $e^{-iH_A t} |\psi\rangle_A$ will still satisfy all the requisite assumptions, and any bipartition of it would give a factorizable evolution, and so on.

A product state has no correlation between each of its components. The moment you introduce interactions (hence correlations), you no longer deal with product states.

@paulina If one has a generic interaction, it's true that the product states will become entangled. But one can concoct interactions that preserve certain product states. An example might be $H = \sum_i (1-\sigma^z_i) V_{i, i+1}$ for an arbitary interaction $V_{i,i+1}$, which keeps the all up state as an eigenstate. That's not quite a perfect example, since the dynamics of the all up state would be trivial in this case, but I hope my point is clear

Somewhat related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/602903

There have been a couple of questions along similar lines here (including by the OP, I believe).

@NorbertSchuch That's right, I've edited those similar questions in. I hope this question has sufficient restrictions that it appears a bit more natural and straightforward to argue about than the ones I've posed before (this one has restriction to time evolution of a single state and restriction to product states rather than generic entangled states whose entanglement doesn't change).

I think it is a good question, and clearly shaped enough to allow for an answer. (My guess would be "yes".)

By the way, it seems that a positive result for a bipartite setting would inductively imply the general result.

@NorbertSchuch Good point! I agree that a positive result in the bipartite setting gives the general result
